# On python swiftclient, Swift upload command being killed Automatically

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Using putty and python swiftclient,  Swift upload command being automatically killed repeatedly.

I am transferring data from a drive connected to a baremetal server to the object storage mounted on the same server.
total transfer size is 2.2 TB with 2 folders of 1.1 TB each.

Using the following command to upload the data:

> [root@baremetal mnt]# swift upload --skip-identical disk2/home -S
>   1073741824 home/
>
> ```
> Killed
> [root@baremetal mnt]# swift upload --skip-identical disk2/data -S 1073741824 data/
>
> Killed
> ```

Security measures taken: 
1. Public port is disabled.
2. Connecting via VPN and using private links

For the first time, we were able to transfer 187.5 GB. We are using --skip-identical to avoid overlaps. which is a time consuming task. And now our both the jobs are being killed automatically. Leading us to stay at 187.5 GB since a day or more.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, it's only possible to upload files 5 GB.

- [Large Object
  Support](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/overview_large_objects.html)

I suggest to submit a ticket to SoftLayer for further assistance